# Need help in understand Django-Facebook API and the Post extraction from a profile using Python2

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on my machine learning project where I am in a great need to access the textual posts of the people from Facebook, of course with permission, and then process it to find the best personality traits.
I am struggling to find a way to merge my application with something that can give me the post of the people from their profiles. Hence, I found something in the documentation of the Django-Facebook API. Here is the link for the [documentation](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Here what I am not able to understand is how can I use this for extracting the post of the people? Can anyone give me a small example that can be helpful in understanding what I can do to extract the text from the people profile and use it in my application.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please? Need serious help...:)

Comment: Try this https://github.com/ramusus/django-facebook-posts

Comment: I am willing to fetch the post. Here the application needs the post ID. How I can conclude the post ID. Instead I was willing to have automatic textual post fetching.

Comment: Try this link, it gives you the posts of the current user as well as of friends which are made public. http://django-facebook-graph.readthedocs.io/en/structured/examples.html#fetch-a-user-s-newsfeed

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Is it possible for you to show any such application as an example that works anywhere so that I can see it myself. I have tried many things But have landed no where as I didn't got any samples to test or even some insights that would be helpful in understand the fact that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: All I can do is suggest, can't suggest any such applications or project. But this project can definitely help. You need to try it to see if its working or not for you.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi After seeing the code I guess it is not what I am looking at. But lets check it out....